# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"api/v1/topics", :format=>:json}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have my topics_controller inside the folder (api/v1/) as

```
class Api::V1::TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    render json: @topics
  end
end
```

When I try to write rspec for above code as :

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::TopicsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "should return a successful response" do
      get :index, format: :json
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"api/v1/topics", :format=>:json}.
```

But I have correct route I don't know why it is showing like that. Any solution are most welcomed.

I have my route as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaluts: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :topics
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: show the routes also

Comment: I have put up my route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in routes:
`namespace :api, defaluts: {format: :json}` => `defaults`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. `defaluts: {format: :json}` should be `defaults: {format: :json}`

Answer (score -2):

Okay guys i had a typo in 'defaults'. Everyone will make typo mistakes so you need not downvote my question.

Comment: It is already mentioned in not one, but two answers here. You may accept one of those instead of repeating their statements.